# If babel is already listed in `dev-dependencies` for jest, why do I need to install it separately?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, jestjs, babel-jest

While setting up my newest project, `npm` seemed to install `babel-core` and `babel-jest` automatically on running `npm install --save-dev jest`.

Since npm's default behavior is to install dev dependencies on installing with `--save-dev` option, why do the docs specify installing babel again -  https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/getting-started.html#using-babel

Comment: jest is using babel for transpiling it library's code, while you'll have to compile your code.